# Best way to return JSON OK status with Spring API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing a simple API in Spring and I'm wondering what is the cleanest way to acknowledge successful calls like updates/deletions which don't return any data with something like

`{status:"ok"}`

I can obviously return a String or predefined OK_Object but there surely must be better way to do it.

Comment: Better suited for code review ?

Comment: if web api, use http status?

Answer (score 3):

I would just return a 204 (no body).

> 10.2.5 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body

see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: This is a good answer to the described problem but what if for example month from now I will like to return number of updated/deleted records? Lets say the format will be `{status:"ok",affectedRecords:30}`? What would be the best strategy to generalize it with Spring.

Comment: @LukaszKujawa What do you want to generalize? And if you have settled on a format anyway then what's your question?